# sample code about esper engine

Tags: java, esper, complex-event-processing

i wanted to begin learning ESPER engine, and i found out that ester native examples are a little complex.

is there any one who has a good simple example java code, which is about using esper?

Answer (score 2):

Try [this example](http://coffeeonesugar.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/getting-started-with-esper-in-5-minutes/). I ran this and starting modifying this yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late, but I would not like to leave this one unmentioned: the Quick Start tutorial. I made it run (with some simple changes to make it Maven-friendly) in one single Pomodoro. :)

http://esper.codehaus.org/tutorials/tutorial/quickstart.html

FWIW